# transfer music/pictures to my lumia 710(windows 7.5 phone)

Tags: 12.04, windows, smartphone

I read some where that if I mount my "Nokia Lumia 710" as a media device i can sync data.

But I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Install libmobiledevices package. If then if you are unable to mount use cloud services as Dropbox or skydrive.